# How to extract test case name, steps, expected result from an automated test framework in to excel

Tags: cucumber-java

I am asked to create a utility to extract the feature file details (name, steps expected values) and display them in excel file without executing any tests.
Then to also get number of test cases in each feature file.

Is there any plugin or report that i can use?
P.s We already have a test report that records the results of the tests run but we just want to get an overall idea about which tests we have and how many tests in each area without running all the tests and then to share this on Jira for the team

Environment: IntelliJ, Java, Cucumber, BDD

Comment: You could write your own plugin. https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/01/cucumber-jvm-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. Put below `ReportPlugin` class somewhere with your step defs or support classes

If you are using junit5 then , in `junit-platform.properties` file add this `cucumber.plugin =com.yourPackage.ReportPlugin` and `cucumber.execution.dry-run= true`

If you are using junit4 then you'll have to add above options in `@cucumberOtions`

Run as usual. Dry run will not execute test cases but will print information . Once you see output in your console , you can then use any excel library to write to excel

You will have to look into [Events](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/4.7.2/cucumber/api/event/EventPublisher.html) to exactly find out which event you need and then modify below code to print that information. Below gives information on some events.

Have a look [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1711), . The below snippet is taken from there and modified for use

```
Package com.yourPackage    
import io.cucumber.plugin.EventListener;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.*;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ReportPlugin implements EventListener {
    

    private final Map<String, Status> finishedCases = new TreeMap<String, Status>();
    private final Map<String, String> startedCases = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    
    @Override

        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseFinished.class, this::handleTestCaseFinished);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseStarted.class, this::handleTestCaseStarted);
        
    }

    private void handleTestCaseFinished(TestCaseFinished event) {
        
        finishedCases.put(event.getTestCase().getUri() + "::::" + event.getTestCase().getLine(),
                event.getResult().getStatus());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Status> entry : finishedCases.entrySet()) {
                String location = entry.getKey();
                Status pattern = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(location + " @@@@fromTestCaseFinished@@@@ " + pattern);
            }
    }
    
    private void handleTestCaseStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
        
        startedCases.put(event.getTestCase().getUri() + "::::" + event.getTestCase().getLine(),
                event.getTestCase().getName());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : startedCases.entrySet()) {
                String location = entry.getKey();
                String pattern = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(location + " !!!!fromTestCaseStarted!!!! " + pattern);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response - user1207289. A bit late response but to make a note here cucumber.execution.dry-run= true worked perfect on this issue. Thanks for your suggestion.